# Edit HTML Table template using PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have PHP code that fetches data from MySQL database and i want to place that data in table format in an already existing html template. I am currently doing it by putting html code in PHP echo. I want to know if there is any better approach?
What i thought of was i place a jquery in php and change the html code using

```
$("").html();
```

but not sure how to add this jQuery script in my HTML as it is inside php?

Comment: could u be give snippet of the code so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you share with us what you have as of now. To answer your question you can place jQuery script inside HTML using script tag.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

});
</script>
```

Comment: But i have to add data retrieved by php to the html..How can i do that if php and html jquery are different files..

Comment: If i get you correctly then what you looking for is AJAX. I suggest it would be easy for you if you can go through how AJAX works. And also like i said before please share what you have so that it would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

a way to do this using old trick 
in the current page use post

```
$.post('page.php', {want:'table'},function(return){
//show data on current page
show(return);
});
```

> php side page.php

```
<?php
   if(!empty($_POST['want']) && $_POST['want']==='table'){
   //fetch data from mysql
   $data=fetch_data();
   header('content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data);
   exit(0);
   }
?>
```